# Remove View details option from plugin listing

Tags: wp-admin

How can I remove "View Details" link from plugins listing in Admin panel without change in WordPress core files.

[image]

Comment: :( the more you try to hide things from admins the more likely they will think you have something to hide

Answer (score 3):

Try following code:

```
add_filter('plugin_row_meta','fun_hide_view_details',10,4);
function fun_hide_view_details($plugin_meta, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $status)
{
  if($plugin_data['slug'] == 'YOUR_PLUGIN_SLUG')
    unset($plugin_meta[2]);
  return $plugin_meta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the plugin name to something unique. If I can remember correctly, this is all that is needed. Just a note though, adhere to any special licence requirements there may be from the original author. Don't make code yours if you did nkot write it, always leave some credit to the author :-)